# “There’s still an outstanding balance...”

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

In the midst of preparing an invoice document for a client, I found myself stuck with this sentence:

> There’s still an outstanding balance of RM 300 to be paid.

Of course in conversational English, I could just say: “Hey dude, you still owe me and this is the amount...” How do I construct a simple sentence to be placed in an invoice document?

These variations lingered in my mind:

> There’s still an outstanding balance of RM 300 to be paid
>
> There’s an unpaid balance of RM 300
>
> There’s still an outstanding unpaid balance of RM 300

Can anyone shed me some light?

Comment: Your first sentence is perfectly fine. My only minor quibble would be that, in writing, I would not abbreviate "*There is*" to "*There's*". In option 3, "outstanding unpaid" is tautological - either word will do, but not both. I may omit "to be paid" from the first sentence. Your second option is also fine, but I think (at least in the UK), "outstanding balance" would be the more usual expression. (If there is any doubt whether it is a debit or credit balance, the inclusion of "unpaid" would make that clear - but it would normally be clear from context (else you wouldn't be chasing them!)).

Comment: Oh yay, awesome! Thanks @TrevorD. You not only shed me some light but a whole room of bright lights! (Ok, that's silly...)

How do I choose your answer and close this question since this is the comments section

Comment: *Unpaid*, *outstanding* (in this context), and *to be paid* all mean the same thing. Choose one and drop the repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [following comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364963/there-s-still-an-outstanding-balance#comment850913_364963) by [@TrevorD](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/43980/trevord) provides a suitable answer:

> Your first sentence is perfectly fine. My only minor quibble would be
> that, in writing, I would not abbreviate *"There is"* to *"There's"*.
> In option 3, "outstanding unpaid" is tautological - either word will
> do, but not both. I may omit "to be paid" from the first sentence.
>
> Your second option is also fine, but I think (at least in the UK),
> "outstanding balance" would be the more usual expression. (If there is
> any doubt whether it is a debit or credit balance, the inclusion of
> "unpaid" would make that clear - but it would normally be clear from
> context (else you wouldn't be chasing them!)).